# Artifacting in model

Tags: modeling, artifacts

I created my first person in Blender.  It's looking ok, except for a strange artifacting at the neck.  I don't know when it first appeared, I didn't notice it until I was done.  You can see from this view, it has no vertices

[image]

In grid view, you can just make out this pyramid shape running from the chin to mid-chest.  Anyone have an idea what it is?

FYI, It's also there in object mode.

[image]

Here is the link to the blender file: [image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks for the reminder.  I was frustrated and wasn't even sure WHAT to ask.

Comment: @moonboots I don't see where to attach a file?

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload

Comment: @moonboots I loaded the Blender file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to go into face select mode and delete it,
my guess is that you accidentally filled an edge loop with a face.

[image]

[image]

This is what it looks like in its entirety.

[image]